# Many G gracefull finishing in server-status

Tags: apache2

In my server-status apache2.4 in ubuntu16.04 i have many G status. somtimes most of 3000 thread is G . Some queries failed.
High G status is problem or not related?
server: 32 core cpu and 128GB RAM

server status :

```
Server load: 21.45 22.57 22.66
Total accesses: 1153411 - Total Traffic: 11.5 GB
CPU Usage: u322.14 s2221.14 cu0 cs0 - 24.1% CPU load
109 requests/sec - 1.1 MB/second - 10.4 kB/request
900 requests currently being processed, 60 idle workers
```

mpm_event config:

```
ServerLimit              140
StartServers             30
MinSpareThreads          35
MaxSpareThreads          80
# ThreadLimit              64
ThreadsPerChild          30
MaxRequestWorkers        4000
MaxConnectionsPerChild   500
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the event MPM, these tie up a thread.  "MaxConnectionsPerChild   500" is exceptionally low and under any non-trivial load you will be constantly killing off processes which will send all their active requests into 'G' state.

Comment: Im using event MPM -> this means that apache dont kill after 500 request?